# Another clarification on Azure DevOps Pipeline: -d--- and -a--- mode

Tags: azure-devops

I do a Download of My Build.SourceDirectories and what is get is of this format:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d-----        3/11/2021   8:51 PM                ReleaseNoteScripts                                                    
d-----        3/11/2021   8:51 PM                Flow_Tools_CodeGen_PS                                           
                                             
-a----        3/11/2021   8:51 PM           1319 README.md
```

I am using this Directory to run a powershell script to upload it in SharePoint. I am able to do it for files with mode  d---  but it fails for file with mode -a--- . In this case, It gives me error as README.MD file is not found. What is -a--- mode and I am ok with README.md file not uploaded in SharePoint. How should I remove that my PowerShell Script don't take this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mode` is a misnomer. It's really `Attributes`:

`d` is a directory, `a` is the archive bit set, `r` is read-only, `s` is system, `h` is hidden, etc.

Why this fails on the `a` entry suggests that your task to upload is only looking at directories and not files at that folder level. Would need to see more to say more.

Comment: thats correct, so is there away to  remove the archive bit set or the files. I am reading $(Build.SourceDirectories)